# Allow local subnet in NGINX with docker network in bridge network

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, nginx-reverse-proxy

In my docker VM I have a container with NGINX web server in a bridge network, it points to a public domain which is working fine. I also added a local DNS record for the domain to resolve to a local IP of a reverse-proxy so I can work locally while also having the advantage of using the same address (when pinging I can see that the local ip address answers). Now while I work on developing that website I added allow and deny records to nginx reverse-proxy block and since I am using Lets Encrypt to generate the certs and these are stored on the machine I want to have a full access to the web server via domain even if my internet connection is down.

nginx block:

```
allow my.local.network.vlan1/24;
allow my.local.network.vlan2/24;
deny all;
```

In error.log I can see:

```
[error] 497#497: *45 access forbidden by rule, client: MY.WAN.IP
```

I tried adding the WAN IP to the rule and it works but why is NGINX not detecting that I'm connecting via LAN and what if the IP changes or I don't have any internet access. Do I need to configure reverse-proxy in host mode?

Answer (score 0):

I was using SWAG as a docker image and Cloudflare as proxy. Had to add their docker mod for real ip and it works fine now.